# Extend forcasting steps greater than 100? in time seires

Tags: time-series

So we are attempting to forecast the prices of stocks from yahoo finance for our senior project.  We have a projection up in a line graph but it will only forecast up to 100 data points (days I believe).  Is there any way to increase the number of prediction points over 100?

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question? do you only have the projection output and not the model itself? could you just feed the output into a new forecasting model...?!